# 'wp_redirect' is not working

Tags: wordpress, redirect

There is an HTML form input. Here's the code:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['login'])) { 
    wp_redirect("/"); 
}

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" >
    ...
    <center><input name="login" type="submit" value="вход" />
</form>
```

But redirect doesn't work. Install debug plugin redirects to wp, that's what it showed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im4eE.png

PS:

```
<?php wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 301 ); exit; ?>
```

It does not work either.

Comment: Try `wp_redirect( home_url() );` instead of `"/"`

Comment: dont work. use the this code: http://goo.gl/U56vzt 
1 и 2 showed. but redirect dont work

Comment: Try this instead of *wp_redirect* `header( 'Location: http://www.google.com/' )`

Comment: wp can block? or write something code in functions.php ?

Answer (score 12):

Use the follwing code:-

```
function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
} // soi_output_buffer
add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');
```

Or add 
    ob_start() as first line of your own function which hook into 'init'

Don't forget to add

```
exit();
```

immediately after your call to

```
wp_redirect($url);
```

link:

https://tommcfarlin.com/wp_redirect-headers-already-sent/

Answer (score 8):

I think your code doesn't begin with that `if` condition!

`wp_redirect` will send an header, so printing/echoing something before it, will have result in failure.

So check and see if before this:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) 
{
    wp_redirect("/");
    exit;
}
```

there is no character out put. Also do not forget to put `exit;` right after `wp_redirect`.

Comment: Make sure to check your `debug.log` under `wp-content` if it states something like: ```[11-Aug-2016 15:30:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/www/my_website/htdocs/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress/custom/templates/header-home.php:65) in /srv/www/my_website/htdocs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1166```

Comment: I was calling var_dump and echo before the redirect. That was my problem. Wouldn't have found it w/o your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Just use this as per below:

```
ob_clean();
$url = get_home_url() . '/login';
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

Or you could use Javascript as well for redirection purpose.

```
<script>window.location='http://www.google.com'</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have: `get_header();` or any wordpress function that potentially creates contents like header and footer in your template. Otherwise the redirection won't work.

Some developers try to clear the page by using `ob_start();` but if you have content in your page even if you use `ob_start();` the redirection won't work.

and then simply try this code:

```
wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->ID));
exit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, which also forces on error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);


flush();
header("Location: http://www.website.com/");
die('should have redirected by now');
```

From [PHP header redirect not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242033/php-header-redirect-not-working)

Edit:

Since it's giving you the `headers already sent` warning, try adding the following at the very **beginning** of your code:

`ob_start();`

> The long term answer is that all output from your PHP scripts should
>   be buffered in variables. This includes headers and body output. Then
>   at the end of your scripts do any output you need.
>
> The very quick fix for your problem will be to add ob_start(); as the
>   very first thing in your script if you only need it in this one
>   script. If you need it in all your scripts add it as the very first
>   thing in your header.php file.
>
> This turns on PHP's output buffering feature. In PHP when you output
>   something (do an echo or print) if has to send the HTTP headers at
>   that time. If you turn on output buffering you can output in the
>   script but PHP doesn't have to send the headers until the buffer is
>   flushed. If you turn it on and don't turn it off PHP will
>   automatically flush everything in the buffer after the script finishes
>   running. There really is no harm in just turning it on in almost all
>   cases and could give you a small performance increase under some
>   configurations...

From [Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707693/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-error/9709170#9709170)

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/site/data/www/site.com/wp-content/themes/site/edit.php:49) in /home/site/data/www/site.com/wp-content/themes/site/edit.php on line 57 should have redirected by now

Comment: now: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /home/site/data/www/site.com/wp-content/themes/site/edit.php on line 58 should have redirected by now

Comment: You **have** to move from line 50 to line 60 to line 1 to 10 ! @Rincver

Comment: function ob_start () I insert in the header.php

Comment: did not understand what I have to?

Comment: You have to put all of your code from line 50 to 60 right after your `ob_start()` (in `header.php`) i.e. these should be the **very first** functions getting called

Comment: No; you have to put your if isset post AND ob_start INSIDE your header.php, at the very beginning

Comment: Yes @rincver - what warning are you getting now when you open the page?

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in /home/site/data/www/site.com/wp-content/themes/site/header.php on line 10 should have redirected by now

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem and none of these solutions worked for me.

The only thing that I noticed is different at the page is that I used `wp_redirect` below `get_header()` and it will work fine if you used it above it.