# Why this redirection isn't working?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm fairly new to Wordpress so not sure what I'm doing wrong. On my Wordpress site, users are able to create custom post types (products). I'm looking to disallow access to a page like this: example.com/post-a-listing by redirecting users to another page if they didn't create at least one product. Here's what I've tried but this isn't working..

```
  function yoursite_user_has_posts($user_id) {
      $result = new WP_Query(array(
        'author'=>$user_id,
        'post_type'=>'product',
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'posts_per_page'=>1,
      ));
      return (count($result->posts)!=0);
    }

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

    function redirect_to_specific_page() {

    if ( is_page('post-a-listing') && ! yoursite_user_has_posts($user_id) ) {

    wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/', 301 ); 
      exit;
        }
```

Comment: I had similar issue sometime back. I have added ob_start() at the top of my script which worked like charm!

Comment: thanks, but where exactly should I place it? Because this code I provided is in the functions.php

Comment: Try 1st & 2nd answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587154/wp-redirect-is-not-working

Comment: Also, try the accepted answer here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179070/wp-redirect-headers-already-sent

Comment: answer there don't seem relative to my question or I'm missing something as non of those answers work for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue for the function is $user_id actually , from where you can get the $user_id with out referencing it?

Use `get_current_user_id()` inside the function to get the current User ID.

```
    function redirect_to_specific_page() {
       $user_id = get_current_user_id();
       if ( is_page('post-a-listing') && ! yoursite_user_has_posts($user_id) ) {
       wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/', 301 ); 
       exit;
       }
    }
```

Comment: sorry, didn't close the brackets :) it works :) thanks!