# WP Redirect function not working on live site

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I tried this code on localhost:

```
<?php wp_redirect('https://google.com/'); exit; ?>
```

On localhost it works well.

As I upload this on live site, It's function wp_redirect does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please specify the environment differences between your localhost and production (Server, PHP versions etc )

Comment: PHP and Wordpress version is same

Comment: when you redirect the page?

Answer (score 0):

You should put this function at the top of the codes.
I suggest you use **init action** for redirect page.

```
add_action('init', function(){
if( isset($_GET['exit']) ) {
wp_redirect('https://google.com/');
 exit;
}
});
```

this code put **functions.php** in your theme.

Comment: More info here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587154/wp-redirect-is-not-working

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code working fine on online page. I add this code: `function app_output_buffer() {
    ob_start();
} // soi_output_buffer

add_action('init', 'app_output_buffer');` and it works