# header location not working on live but working in localhost

Tags: php

```
include "include/connection.php";
$date= date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$profile_comment="INSERT INTO `infotown_test`.`profile_comments` (`id`, `user_id`, `name`, `email`, `comments`, `date_and_time`) VALUES (NULL, '".$_REQUEST['user_id']."', '".$_REQUEST['name']."', '".$_REQUEST['email']."', '".$_REQUEST['comment']."', '".$date."')";
mysql_query($profile_comment);
header("location:company-profile.php?id=2");(why it's not working?)
```

Comment: do you have any html content or echo before that header?

Comment: use $id = mysql_insert_id(); I think it is not working because of id

Comment: Check query error before header. You should ON your error reporting in development mode.

Comment: Try `exit()` after `header()` function.

Comment: use ob_start(); at the start of the script.

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: @syed mohamed: no html content or echo....

Comment: @Jitendra: I tried without id like index.php

Comment: Guys I already tried your all suggestions.......

Comment: try --> mysql_query($profile_comment) or die('Error');   and see if you get any error

Comment: @n01ze: I used no error showing.

Comment: @nitul ok , the record is getting inserted huh ?!

Comment: @n01ze: yes record inserted into datbase

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP header redirect not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242033/php-header-redirect-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Make the "**location**" Capital to "**Location**",

`header("Location:company-profile.php?id=2");`