# How to fix this php header redirect

Tags: php, redirect, header

This is the code ....

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/search.php&checkin_monthday=".$Checkin_date."&checkin_month=".$Checkin_month."&checkin_year=".$Checkin_year."&checkout_monthday=".$Checkout_date."&checkout_month=".$Checkout_month."&checkout_year=".$Checkout_year.");
```

This is not working. Please kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: what error are  you getting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242033/php-header-redirect-not-working

Comment: If I recall correctly, browsers only follow a `Location` header if the HTTP status code is in the 300s.

Answer (score -1):

header is wrong, you forgot to close the last quote, either remove it or close it

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/search.php&checkin_monthday=".$Checkin_date."&checkin_month=".$Checkin_month."&checkin_year=".$Checkin_year."&checkout_monthday=".$Checkout_date."&checkout_month=".$Checkout_month."&checkout_year=".$Checkout_year);
```

Comment: is this not working?